# Get the selected value of a Selectlist. Asp.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Im trying to get the selected value from selectlist before I submit the form? How can I do this?

It will be great if I can get the selected value in view not in controller Is there any way to do that?

Thanks

Comment: Use client-side script and post the post to a new endpoint?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/get-selected-value-in-dropdown-list-using-javascript